# rand() generating 0 value instead of null for empty array in perl

Tags: perl

```
if (@_ && @$types && $types->[0]) {
    # Random array lookup
    print "@_\n"; #([])
    ("\@{$_[0]}&&$_[0]\->[rand(\@{$_[0]})]", chooseType($_[0]))
}
```

I want to return `nul` instead of `0`, as the array is empty.

Comment: line 4 is a useless use of string in a void context.

Comment: How is it possible for you to be inside the if-block, because if `@_` is empty, you will never hit the rest of the lines?

Comment: that is useful in case of array consisting of some values like ([(1),(3),(8),(6)])

Comment: ok, fine, but then you will never handle the case where the array is empty.

Comment: yes, that is the issue which i am facing.

Comment: Well, there is no `nul` in perl, there is `undef`.  You could just `print "[]\n" unless scalar @_;`

Comment: 0 means the array is empty, as in it has 0-elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
@a ? int(rand(@a)) : undef
```